# It's not saving value into database table, why?

Tags: python, database, django, forms, django-models

```
def register(request):
    flag = True
    possible = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    token = ''
    length = 10
    i = 0

    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

    user = UsersModelForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userf = UsersModelForm(request.POST)
        username = userf.data['username']
        password = userf.data['password']
        passwordrepeat = userf.data['passwordrepeat']
        email = userf.data['email']

        if password != passwordrepeat:
            flag = False
            passVariable = {'user':user, 'flag': False}
            return render_to_response('register.html', passVariable, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        elif password == passwordrepeat:
            for i in range(1,10):
                temp = random.choice(possible)
                token = token + temp

            print token
            userf.email_token = token
            userf.email_token_expiry = current_datetime + timedelta(1)
            if userf.is_valid():
                check = userf.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

userf.save() is inserting a row, but it's not saving email_token, email_token_expiry, it's only inserting username,password,email and the default value as it's in models.py.

models.py:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    passwordrepeat = models.CharField('Repeat Password', max_length=300)
    password_token = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='0')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email_token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_token_expiry = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_action = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

class UsersModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'passwordrepeat', 'email')
        widgets = {
            'password' : PasswordInput(),
            'passwordrepeat' : PasswordInput(),
        }
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem? Why isn't saving values to other fields?

Comment: 1. You haven't read the documentation about model forms. 2. You're **still** attempting to save passwords in clear in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        if userf.is_valid():
            user = userf.save(commit=False)
            user.email_token = token
            user.email_token_expiry = current_datetime + timedelta(1)
            user.save()
```

Comment: Why do i have to use this way? What's the problem with normal `userf.save()` way?

Comment: `userf` is actually an instance of `UserModelForm`, not of `Users`. If you really want to assign it to `userf` you should assign to `userf.data['email_token']`, I think that would work, but I'm not sure. I would just do it my way.

Comment: I got error after submitting the form, `IntegrityError at /register

(1048, "Column 'email_token_expiry' cannot be null")` http://pastebin.com/LxzY5Vs6

Comment: It's still not saving token, that's amazing problem.

Comment: That code does not correspond to the code I gave you. You need to assign to `check.email_token`, not to `userf.email_token`.

Comment: @guru: You're welcome. You can mark the question as solved by clicking the checkmark on the left of the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's only inserting values for the fields you have specified in `fields`. Add email_token, email_token_expiry to that list and those will also be saved to the database.

EDIT: Whoops, yeah. Do this instead:

```
check = userf.save(commit=False)
check.email_token = token
check.email_token_expiry = current_datetime + timedelta(1)
check.save()
```

The form object won't save additional info attached to it (AFAIK). You need to get the object back from save() and then assign those values. `commit=False` keeps the form from saving to the database. Then you add the extra info you need and save the object.

Comment: No, if you add `email_token`, and `email_token_expiry` in fields array, `{{ form }}` will display those textboxed too in templates.

Comment: I got error after submitting the form, `IntegrityError at /register

(1048, "Column 'email_token_expiry' cannot be null")` http://pastebin.com/LxzY5Vs6

Comment: It's still not saving token, that's amazing problem. http://pastebin.com/duNJZWjz

Comment: @Tom, there is problem with your code, it would be `check.email_token` and `check.email_token_expiry`

Comment: Ah geez, that's what I get for editing while watching football. Sorry.